# sculpting and connecting from different bodyparts

Tags: objects, sculpting

I am beginner and sculpt a body at the moment.
I guess my way wasn't very effective.

I created a body with different body parts. Each body part is a separate object.
I sculpt mostly and I realized I wanna connect the different object to sculpt in a better way.
This should be the way anyway at the end.
I have no idea how to do this.
I used a subdivision surface mod and it is just.. messy.
In a old video I have seen there is a kind of bridge addon?

I would be happy for any recommendation or tip.
I attach a picture.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the Boolean modifier:
Let's say that you wanna connect one arm to the torso (this will be the main object):

0.- (Optional) Select the arm, go to Object properties > Viewport Display, select Wireframe and change the "Display on" to Wire.

1.-Select the Torso, go to Modifier > Boolean : Change the "operation" to "Union" and in "object" Select the Arm.

2.- Click "Apply" and turn Off or delete the arm Object.

Now you have one Object made with the torso and the arm.

Repeat that with every part that you wanna connect to the torso and after that, add a subdivision and apply.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Good answer. This really is one of the the best cases for using Booleans in my view: Combining sculpts. Especially if you're going to be sculpting with Dyntopo, since the resulting topology kinks that can often arise from using Booleans are of no consequence in that case, beause you'll be retopologizing later anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much!
This is exactly what I looked for. 
I was looking in so many posts and tried different ways. 
This way works so well!
Thanks