# How to sculpt two meshes to look as one

Tags: sculpting

[image]I am new to sculpting and I am trying to figure out how to make two meshes seem to be made as one. I have heard of the Boolean modifier, but I just get what I had before with extra dots all over one object. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

This is what I have. I found a good example for what I am going for in the Blender 2.83 Sculpting Time lapse- Gotic Witch by Guilia Marchetti. There is a before and after image. The technique used here was the grab tool in sculpt mode. I can't seem to get that to work.[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add some images to your post that demonstrate your problem in more detail. Your question is kind of vague as-is. Possibly consider uploading your .blend file as well. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183227/sculpting-and-connecting-from-different-bodyparts/183231#183231

Comment: Emir's link above has the answer you're looking for. You need to use the boolean modifier to join (Union) each part of your character before sculpting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sculpting and connecting from different bodyparts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183227/sculpting-and-connecting-from-different-bodyparts)

Comment: I tried the method on your forwarded question, and it is causing my file to crash. Don't worry, I can recover the autosave. I had an idea for using the fill tool after joining them, and I got pretty good results. I had to make a new limb in a new file because the other one is not loading, so it should work in the main one when it loads.