# How would I combine these two models in sculpt mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, geometry

[image]

I'm trying to merge this box onto this helmet using sculpt mode. I've seen this done before but I don't remember how. I tried using a boolean but there were some edge errors. I might be wrong but it seemed like there was a simple solution.

[image]

That little box thing on his helmet in the reference picture is how it should look.

[image]
This is what happens when I use remesh.

[image]

This little artifact is what happens when I use a union boolean.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sculpting and connecting from different bodyparts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183227/sculpting-and-connecting-from-different-bodyparts)

Comment: I've already tried using a union boolean. I added a picture so you can see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Join the two objects with Ctrl J (if not already joined), then in sculpt mode press Shift R to set a resolution and Ctrl R to perform a Remesh operation.

The mesh has to be Manifold: no holes, no doubles, no hidden internal faces.
It can be unefficient with close geometries (like fingers on a hand).

Comment: Whenever I do that, the mesh gets a bunch of tiny holes and basically destroys itself. I added a picture to show what it looks like.

Comment: Go to edit mode, choose vertex selection mode, go to menu: Select > Select All by trait > Non Manifold, to check where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just manually combine the two meshes by merging their vertices and editing the helmet's vertex structure. This is probably the way that you should do it anyway because it doesn't use any fancy features and just makes a clean quad mesh.

[image]